# Is Challenge Difficulty Completely Random?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I've noticed that once I completed the heavy blaster challenge, which was something like: "kill 25 people with heavy blasters", the next challenge was kill 75 people will blasters, and the rewards were larger.

This leads me to wonder, do the challenges increase in difficult, and thus reward, as you completed them.  Or are challenges and their difficulty totally random?

Can one receive the same challenge for the same quantity twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BocChoy314](https://www.reddit.com/user/BocChoy314) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)'s [battlefront subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefront/) [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefront/comments/3uybp4/is_challenge_difficulty_completely_random/):

> To answer your question, I have received the same challenges multiple
>   times. I think it's totally random. If you don't like a challenge you
>   can pay 500 credits for a new one, which is lame in and of itself.

Comment: Can confirm this.  I've paid to change out a challenge, only to get the same one again appear.  Had there been any sorting or thought behind the challenge, it would have some way to avoid the same challenge unless there was something like a tier of them to unlock. (which isn't the case here)